# How can I use make to maintain a common C++ header include directory?

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files

My project consists of about a dozen components, and source code for each of these lives in its own subdirectory under the main source code directory.  Many of the components use header files from other components, and I'm trying to arrange things so that these header files are all available in a single `include/` directory.  Stop me now if this is a bad idea or if there's a better way to make headers from one component easily available to another.

It's simple enough to copy a component's headers to `include/` after the component is built: `cp *.hpp ../include` in the makefile works well.  But when `make clean` is run on an individual component, I want to remove that component's headers from `include/` without removing any others.  As far as I can tell, this means I have to maintain a list of the component's header files in a "remove" command in the makefile, like this:

```
clean:
    rm -fv ../include/header1.hpp ../include/header2.hpp ...
```

Maintaining this list is manual work, which I'd like to automate.  I want to get this right, because I anticipate problems if a component which depends on the copied header gets built before a new version of the same header is copied into place - very time-consuming-to-diagnose problems.

How can I get my makefile to clean up a list of headers in a separate directory?  Alternatively, is there a better way to make my header files available to other components in the same project?

Comment: So you have directories componentA, componentB etc with headers a.h and b.h, right? Why do you prefer #include <a.h> and #include <b.h> over #include <componentA/a.h> and #include <componentB/b.h>? Also in that last case you just tell the compiler to look in the project root for includes and you're done.

Comment: @stijn: `#include "componentA/a.h"` is a bad idea, because it locks the source code to a particular directory structure in the build system. The code shouldn't have to know anything about that, and a change in the directory structure should not break the code.

Comment: Does your build process involve generating the header files from something else? If so, what and where?

Comment: @Beta tons of libraries out there use it with no problems whatsoever. Sure it obliges you to use some structure, but whether or not structure is bad doesn't obey one single rule. 'lock' sounds too strict here. If you rename the directory, just refactor the code as well. It's not like your writing #include </path/to/x/y/z/foo.h> here: the code still doesn't know where componentA is.. Might as well be a symlink. It also allows for more than one header with a given name. Thinking of it, it gives you a similar structure namespaces provide. And those are not known for being bad either.

Comment: @stijn: "No problems whatsoever... just refactor the code." Better still, remove the paths from the code once and for all. I was going to say that a path in an `#include` directive is a nuisance and accomplishes nothing that can't be done by the build system (which has to do it anyway), but I have to amend that: it's a nuisance that -- as you point out -- allows one source file to use two headers with the same name, which really shouldn't be done at all. That fact that it's crudely similar to good tools doesn't make it a good tool.

Comment: @Beta Nope, the files aren't generated.  My goal is to minimise the knowledge each class's implementation file needs to have about the structure of the project, which is generally good practice but extra-important in this case because we've agreed that we should have a sensible directory structure, but we haven't yet agreed on what it should be - so things will likely change soon.  I think @larsmans suggestion of keeping all the headers in the `include` directory and not duplicating them at all is probably the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively, is there a better way to make my header files available to other components in the same project?

There are two obvious and simple ways:

1. keep all the headers in the `include` dir in the first place
2. set up `CPPFLAGS` for each component to tell it where to find its dependencies.

I'd recommend the former approach for small, tightly-coupled projects. The second approach is better for really componentized systems, as it forces you to think about the internal dependencies in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the files and using the copies to build other components is error prone no matter how you do it, manually or not. larsmans suggested some alternatives above.

But if you want to stay with the copy-on-build method, cleaning up through make can be done like this:

```
TO_COPY = $(wildcard *.hpp)
TO_REMOVE = $(patsubst %.hpp, ../include/%.hpp, $(TO_COPY))
```

The first variable will contain all .hpp files in the current directory, the second one will contain the same files with `../include/` prepended to each filename.
So you can copy the files to the include folder with:

```
cp $(TO_COPY) ../include/
```

and remove them at the end with:

```
rm $(TO_REMOVE)
```